# Why is jmsTemplate always null? Using spring and Apache ActiveMQ

Tags: java, spring, jms, mule, activemq-classic

Im very new to Spring and JMS. Ive been trying to come up with an implementation that involves activemq and Spring as follows.

```
spring-context.xml
<bean id="sampleApacheConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
    <property name="userName" value=“kodeseeker"/>
    <property name="password" value=“mypassword"/>

</bean>

 <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="sampleApacheConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!--  Default Destination Queue Definition-->
    <bean id="defaultDestination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="test.Foo"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- JmsTemplate Definition -->
    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="defaultDestination" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Message Sender Definition -->
    <bean id="messageSender" class="com.mypackage.Publisher2">
    </bean>

<!-- Message Receiver Definition -->
    <bean id="messageReceiver" class="com.mypackage.Listener">

    </bean>
       <bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="destinationName" value="test.Foo" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageReceiver" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Publisher2.java

```
public class Publisher2 {

 @Autowired
 protected JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
 .......
// function called to perform update.
  public void publishUpdate(final CustomMessage payload) throws JMSException {
      LOGGER.entry();
      try {
          JmsTemplate jmsTemp= this.jmsTemplate;
          if(jmsTemp ==null){
        //jmsTemplate is ALWAYS null.
           LOGGER.error("Jms Template is never initialized!!");
           return;
          }
          jmsTemp.send(new MessageCreator(){
         @Override
         public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
             Message message = message(payload,session);    
             LOGGER.info("Sending message");
             return message;
        }
        });
      } catch (Exception jmsExcpetion) {
          LOGGER.error("Error placing message on Queue",jmsExcpetion);
     
      }
      LOGGER.exit();
  }
}
```

Is there anything I specifically need to do in order to initialize `jmsTemplate`? Id be happy to provide any more details if necessary .

**Edit 1:**
Class calling the `publishupdate`

```
public class UpdateHandlerImpl implements UpdateHandler {
    private final Publisher2 publisher;
    ....
    public UpdateHandlerImpl() {
        this(new Publisher2());
    }
    public UpdateHandlerImpl(
            final Publisher2 publisher) {
           this. publisher = publisher;
    }
    ....
    @Override
    public void  handle(final CustomMessage entity) {
        try {
                     publisher. publishUpdate(entity);
        } catch (final JMSException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error sending message", e);
        }

            }
   …..
    }
```

**Edit 3:** 
Updated version of UpdateHandlerImpl based on @keith's input

```
public class UpdateHandlerImpl implements UpdateHandler {
    //Hoping spring wires this?
    Publisher2 publisher;
    @Override
    public void  handle(final CustomMessage entity) {
        try {
                     publisher. publishUpdate(entity);
        } catch (final JMSException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error sending message", e);
        }

            }
   …..
    }
```

**Edit 2:**
The spring context is loaded through mule( this is a mule application) on startup using the following annotation.

```
<spring:beans>
        <spring:import resource="classpath:spring-context.xml" />
    </spring:beans>
```

Comment: Show the class where you're calling `publishUpdate`.

Comment: @chrylis . Added details. I hope it has all the required info, if not feel free to ask. I can provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating `Publisher2` using `new`, you will not have the dependencies wired on the instance you create. Instead, define it as a Spring bean in your context file and get it from there.

#### Edit

It's as I suspected, in your latest update to the question you confirmed that you are creating a `Publisher2` with new.

```
public UpdateHandlerImpl() {
        this(new Publisher2());
    }
```

This is not how Spring works. See [Section 6.3.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html) of the Spring Framework documentation on instantiating beans. (In short, create the bean using the **context**)

Comment: Thanks for answering .. But am I not doing that already in the spring-context file 
    `<bean id="messageSender" class="com.mypackage.Publisher2">
    </bean>` based on the link you provided.

Comment: You shouldn't be instantiating _any_ objects in your code that you expect Spring to wire for you. In this case, the `new Publisher2())` is defeating your use of dependency injection since that is not a bean managed by the framework.

Comment: I added the following line to the `spring-context.xml`. `<beans>
    <bean name="publisher" class="com.mypackage.Publisher2"/>
</beans>` and removed instantiation. ie. made the new class like [this](http://codeshare.io/adewd). But jmsTemplate continues to be null. What am i missing?

Comment: Spring doesn't work with "hope". You have to tell Spring to inject the dependencies in the class, either with the Autowired annotation on the field and Component on the class (to make it a Spring bean) or with a bean definition in the XML (you also have to define UpdateHandlerImpl as Spring bean).

Comment: Hope....  Too funny, but disappointed to hear it.