# What am I doing wrong in injecting these spring beans? Using Autowiring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mule, spring-annotations

This is is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226948/why-is-jmstemplate-always-null-using-spring-and-apache-activemq?noredirect=1#comment54259805_33226948) question and uses [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null) as a reference.

Here is my modified `spring-context.xml`

```
<bean id="sampleApacheConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
    <property name="userName" value=“kodeseeker"/>
    <property name="password" value=“mypassword"/>

</bean>

 <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="sampleApacheConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!--  Default Destination Queue Definition-->
    <bean id="defaultDestination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="test.Foo"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- JmsTemplate Definition -->
    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="defaultDestination" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Message Sender Definition -->
    <bean id="messageSender" class="com.mypackage.Publisher2">
    </bean>

<!-- Message Receiver Definition -->
    <bean id="messageReceiver" class="com.mypackage.Listener">

    </bean>
       <bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="destinationName" value="test.Foo" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageReceiver" />
    </bean>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" /> 
    <bean name=“publisher" class=“com.mypackage.Publisher2"/>
        <bean name="updateHandler" class="com.mypackage.UpdateHandlerImpl”/>    

</beans>
```

And the incoming class that first receives the request.

```
package com.mypackage

@ComponentScan
@Controller
@Path("/")
public class BaseApiImpl  {

…..
    @Context
    HttpHeaders headers;
    @Autowired
    UpdateHandlerImpl updateHandler;


    @PUT
    @Path("v1/“)
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    public PutTransactionsResponse updateTransactions(
            UpdateTransactionsRequest entity)
            throws Exception {
     // @formatter:on
        LOGGER.entry();
        try {
        //updateHandler is always Null!
              return updateHandler.handle(new UpdateTransactionsMessage(headers.getRequestHeaders(), entity));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.catching(e);
                   } finally {
            LOGGER.exit();
        }

    }
```

However, despite annotating the class with `@Controller` and declaring the beans in the context file . I find that `updateHandler` is always null. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your update handler bean is inside <beans/> which is inside other <beans/> tag... Maybe that's the issue

Comment: Yes your context is messed up. You should format it.

Comment: Your bean is a JAX-RS bean not a spring bean. You will have 2 instances one spring managed and one jax-rs bean. Use the proper integration for the framework you are using or use Spring MVC to expose your rest endpoint. Also `@ComponentScan` isn't going to work on this class that is only useful on `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: @Nadir,  I corrected the typo but the error persists.

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you have an example for the integration? Im very new to Spring.

Comment: Here it is : http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/

Comment: I'm using a mule application, so I dont have a `web.xml` as referenced in the example. How would I proceed?

Comment: Why is there a ComponentScan in controller, it wont help. Also, your autowiring a UpdateHandlerImpl. Try auto-wiring to its interface, same with BaseAPIImpl. Lastly, your spring-context.XML looks messed up. Clean it up.

Comment: Also if you have annotated your classes properly, then consider instructing Spring to register those annotated classes as beans. No need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Jersey Config class and register it as bean and remove `@Component` and `@ComponentScan` on `BaseApiImpl` class, Hopefully it should work, in my case i am using Spring boot.

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath; 

@ApplicationPath(value = "/<contextpath>")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig{

  public JerseyConfig() {
    packages(true, "<your @Path classes package>");
  }
}
```